# Localhost url change to server url

Tags: wordpress

In localhost, my url is write like this in android studio:

```
"http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/reward/v1/userLogin.php"
```

How I write the url in server? Now i put in demo. Thanks You

Comment: problem not clear

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  I'm assuming you want php, since you tagged it as wordpress.

```
$url = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Comment: now my android studio is write like this: 
public static final String URL_LOGIN = "http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/reward/v1/userLogin.php"    now i put the reward file inside live server wp-content, but it come out no page found

Comment: Try $_SERVER[“SERVER_HOST”].$_SERVER[“REQUEST_URI”]. TBH I’m really not understanding what’s your asking for / what you need

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused by what `url in server` means. I'm assuming it means you want your wordpress domain to replace localhost, in that hypothetical case it'd probably be:
`http://yourwordpressdomain.wordpress.com/Wordpress/wp-content/reward/v1/userLogin.php`

Comment: I use the url on server, but i test this url in browser, it show this message:      The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: That sounds like an internal network-configuration problem, and I can't solve that without being within your network.